# Vanilla JS Find Element with Missing Child Element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a boolean that will let me know if a parent element has a child element. Some of the constraints are:

1. There can be x number of these "boxes"
2. Check and see for any of the boxes have a footer element
3. If the box does not have a footer element, add a class

   `<div class="data-trend">
     <header></header>
     <div class="main"></div>
     <footer></footer>
   </div>`

   `<div class="data-trend">
     <header></header>
     <div class="main"></div>
     <footer></footer>
   </div>`

   `<div class="data-trend">
     <header></header>
     <div class="main">
       <span class="glyphicons"><span>
       <!-- On the glyphicons I would add class if there is no footer -->
     </div>
     <!-- notice no footer -->
   </div>`

Comment: I have tried to `querySelector` and then do a `find`. from that I have tried to check the length but because there are 3 boxes, I will never get a value of 0. I have tried to use `contains` and that did not work either.

Comment: Something like this ought to work: `var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.data-trend'), len = elems.length, i = -1; while(++i < len) { if(!elems[i].querySelector('footer')) elems[i].classList.add('no-footer'); }`

Comment: yes but then how do I take the elems and figure out which of them does not have a footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved the above comment into an actual answer:

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.data-trend'),
    len = elems.length,
    i = -1
while(++i < len) {
  if(!elems[i].querySelector('footer')) elems[i].classList.add('no-footer')
}
```

```css
.no-footer { border: 3px solid blue; }
```

```html
<div class="data-trend">
  <header>Testing</header>
  <div class="main"></div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>

<div class="data-trend">
  <header>Testing</header>
  <div class="main"></div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>

<div class="data-trend">
  <header>Testing</header>
  <div class="main">
    <span class="glyphicons"><span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you're doing a lot of this in vanilla, it makes sense to define a `forEach` helper function for yourself

```
function forEach(elems, fn){
  var len = elems.length,
      i = -1
  while(++i < len) {
    fn(elems[i])
  }
}
```